# Dúvida sobre mySQL - Gravar, Atualizar e Mostrar dados

Tags: html, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Fala galera! Estou com uma dúvida. Criei uma página estática que irá mostrar alguns dados.
Por exemplo, quero mostrar o resultado ao vivo de um jogo específico de futebol.
[image: Exemplo "Mostrar Dados" - Página Estática]

Pensei em criar uma página estática com:

- "Nome do Campeonato"
- "Nome do Time A"
- "Emblema do Time A" (Imagem)
- "Nome do Time B"
- "Emblema do Time B"  (Imagem)
- "Resultado do Jogo"

Para facilitar a entrada de dados pensei em construir um formulário para inserir essas informações em um banco de dados. Mas estou em dúvida se essa é a melhor forma de executar.

1 - É possível eu criar uma página "Inserir dados", deixar pré cadastrado os times/campeonatos e selecionar através de um formulário com caixa de seleção? Por exemplo:

[image: Página"Inserir dados" - Formulário]

2 - É ao enviar o formulário acima ele sempre substituir a linha na tabela? Assim na página de mostrar sempre iria buscar o mesmo dado?

Obrigado por sua atenção.

Comment: Possível é, a questão é que vc tem várias formas de fazer isso. Achei meio genérica tua pergunta

Comment: Então @EmirMarques eu queria saber a forma mais fácil de resgatar estes valores. Pois na página "envia formulário" vou criar uma caixa de seleção com os valores a serem gravados. Por exemplo, ao selecionar "Cruzeiro" e gravar. Quando abrir a página "Mostrar Dados" ele vai atualizar com os dados gravados na tabela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só com HTML e MySQL não - voc^vai precisar ter uma outra tecnologia no meio - uma linguagem de programação no backend: seja Python, PHP, ou outra.

Pode ser possível fazer algo conectando diretamente o Javascript de html-5 com o Banco de dados - no entanto não vejo muta getne fazendo isso, e seria algo inerentemente inseguro: se você tentar fazer isso a chance maior é que de acesso irrestrito a qualquer pessoa a todo o seu banco de dados. (é possível fazer "direito", mas vai exigir um nível de personalização do seu bancod e dados bem diferente do uso comum de bancos e  exigira bem mais expertise do que, digamos, desenvolver o que você precisa em PHP ou usando um framework Python como Flask ou Web2Py)

Answer (score 0):

Para gravar em python a gravação fica assim :

```
from flask import Flask,request,redirect,url_for,render_template
import mysql, MySQLdb, mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

DB = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost", 
  port="3306",
  user="usuario",
  password="senha",
  database="banco",
  auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
  )

conexao = DB.cursor()

SQL_COMMAND = "INSERT INTO tabela(campeonato, timea, timeb, resultado) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s )"
VALORES = [
  ('CAMPEONATO', 'TIMEA', 'TIMEB', 'RESULTADO')
]

conexao.executemany(SQL_COMMAND, VALORES) 

DB.commit()

conexao.close()

DB.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

espero ter ajudado